# How to specify a storage_class when uploading to AWS S3 with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have this code:

```rb
    Aws.config.update(
      region: Settings.cloud_config['region'],
      credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(
        Settings.cloud_config['access_key_id'],
        Settings.cloud_config['secret_access_key']
      )
    )
    s3       = Aws::S3::Resource.new
    bucket   = s3.bucket(Settings.cloud_config['bucket'])
    object   = bucket.object(base_aws_path)
    uploaded = object.upload_file(target_path)
    url      = object.public_url
    size     = object.size
```

This is working great and uploads the file using the S3 "STANDARD" storage class.

In the documentation I can see a method called object.initiate_multipart_upload which accepts this parameter:

```rb
storage_class: "STANDARD", # accepts STANDARD, REDUCED_REDUNDANCY, STANDARD_IA, ONEZONE_IA, INTELLIGENT_TIERING, GLACIER, DEEP_ARCHIVE, OUTPOSTS, GLACIER_IR
```

However, I am not able to find anything like this for upload_file? - what can I pass to upload file or to Aws.config to select the desired storage class?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, so while this appears to be undocumented (unless I missed something?), this works as intended and the files have the expected storage_class in the AWS web portal:

```rb
object.upload_file(target_path, storage_class: 'ONEZONE_IA')
```